# Windows 7 ICS from ethernet, to ethernet

Tags: windows, icalendar

I have my desktop PC with 2 ethernet ports, onboard motherboard ethernet and PCI ethernet card.

I have connectivity to the internet from my router via the PCI card, and want to extend and share the internet from my PC to the onboard motherboard ethernet.

I have done the following steps:

1. Right clicked PCI ethernet card, properties, sharing tab, checked both boxes.
2. Plugged in my ethernet cable to my other PC to the onboard slot and failed to get a connection. The onboard card is configured for DHCP on both IPv4 and IPv6.

Anything obvious I have missed?

Comment: This issue is simple and can be fixed but your question will be flagged as off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to create a bridge.

The process is outlined here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-network-bridge#1TC=windows-7

Basically, you need to select your two network connections and select the "Bridge" option. You will need to have admin rights.

Comment: Done this, my other device still fails to connect via DHCP!